# Overflow-y scroll specific child of a fixed element with 100vh without showing the scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a "flyout" on my page to show search results. I want the flyout to be `100vh` and `fixed` position on the page. Inside the flyout I am showing a bunch of search results and I want the container for the results to be able to scroll but without the scrollbar showing. Here's what I have tried:

```css
.container {
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 15px;
}

.search-container {
  width:40vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
  .search-container form {
    margin:1.5rem 0;
  }
  .search-results {
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-container">
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    
    <div class="search-results">
      <div class="result">
        <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum tellus nec urna dignissim ullamcorper. Sed vitae erat ultricies, elementum ligula sit amet, maximus leo. Nunc nec arcu ante. Proin commodo est orci, ornare laoreet ipsum mollis in. Donec egestas sollicitudin ultrices. Nam quis tempus nunc, vulputate luctus mi.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum tellus nec urna dignissim ullamcorper. Sed vitae erat ultricies, elementum ligula sit amet, maximus leo. Nunc nec arcu ante. Proin commodo est orci, ornare laoreet ipsum mollis in. Donec egestas sollicitudin ultrices. Nam quis tempus nunc, vulputate luctus mi.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum tellus nec urna dignissim ullamcorper. Sed vitae erat ultricies, elementum ligula sit amet, maximus leo. Nunc nec arcu ante. Proin commodo est orci, ornare laoreet ipsum mollis in. Donec egestas sollicitudin ultrices. Nam quis tempus nunc, vulputate luctus mi.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum tellus nec urna dignissim ullamcorper. Sed vitae erat ultricies, elementum ligula sit amet, maximus leo. Nunc nec arcu ante. Proin commodo est orci, ornare laoreet ipsum mollis in. Donec egestas sollicitudin ultrices. Nam quis tempus nunc, vulputate luctus mi.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently the `.search-results` container is not scrolling. The way I want it to work is that the form will always be visible at the top of the flyout, but you should be able to scroll the `.search-results` container to see the rest of the content. Ideally the scrollbar would also not be visible on the element to keep it looking clean, but if it is necessary I can live with it.

Comment: You can't scroll `.search-results` because it's height has expanded to fit the contents of it - there's nothing to scroll as far as the browser is concerned.  You need to constrain it to the bounds of the parent in order for it to scroll

Comment: @Martin ahhh that makes perfect sense, thank you!